# Specifying the Runtime in java.

Tags: java, jar, runtime

I am currently trying to run a Jar file. The problem is, the program is made in a way like: http://www.codingbat.com/, so of course, it needs to compile the code as it goes, and use reflection to run it. The issue I am getting, is the fact that it does not specify that is must use JDK7 instead of the default.

Also, I am just wondering in the Runtime class, would the Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary(String libname) work if I set it to the folder directory of JDK7?

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that in Java Web Start. For a JAR there is no specific to force a JVM to use.

One less graceful way would be to compile your classes with `-target version` javac parameter, so the byte code generated would be specific to target version you state. That would lead to an `UnsupportedClassVersionError` when the application is run using a JVM lower than what was mentioned in the "target"

Comment: This is offline just for reference. Also, would the Runtime method work as I stated above, or is this the only way?